# Server seems to behave in an other way than local application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I developed a formular that should be editable by a customer if wanted. In my local application there's everything running properly when I want to update the form, **but** as soon as I try to update the formular on the website, an error is thrown. Here's the code where the error is located.

```
objectCollection = db.SelectFragebogen(sid, cbControls, tbControls);
objectCollection.RemoveAt(0);

try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (cbControls.Count + tbControls.Count); i++)
    {
        if (i < cbControls.Count)
        {
           if ((bool)objectCollection.ElementAt(i) != cbControls.ElementAt(i).Checked) { cbUpdate.Add(cbControls.ElementAt(i)); }
        }
        else
        {
           if ((string)objectCollection.ElementAt(i) != tbControls.ElementAt(i - cbControls.Count).Text) { tbUpdate.Add(tbControls.ElementAt(i - cbControls.Count)); }
        }
    }
    db.UpdateFragebogen(sid, cbUpdate, tbUpdate);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    Response.Redirect("EmptySite.aspx");
}
```

db.SelectFragebogen is selecting the whole formular from the database. RemoveAt just removes the ID of the form. cbControls is a list of Checkbox-Elements and tbControls is a list of Textbox-Elements. They are getting filled properly, I checked that.

So now we have the objectCollection, where the "old" values are saved, and the 2 lists of controls, where the "new" values are.
The for-loop will now compare the old and the new values and write the changes in an extra collection (cbUpdate and tbUpdate), because I somehow need to know what gets updated.

As I said, if I run this in my local application everything's fine and it's working without any problems. As soon as I try to update a form on my website, an error gets thrown.

The error is an "Index out of range"-error.

Comment: `ex.Message.ToString()` is redundant. You should prefer something like `ex.ToString()` or a professional logging framework. Or even better: Show the error to the user.

Comment: I would but the error message is in german and I guess I wouldnt translate it properly.

Comment: Looks like `objectCollection` doesn't have as many elements as you think

Comment: i think the error is thrown since you don't have checking if `objectCollection` had items on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug the try block and see which line throws the IndexOutOfRange exception, and check the value of i, when it does. It's probably as simple as changing

```
(cbControls.Count + tbControls.Count)
```

to

```
(cbControls.Count + tbControls.Count) - 1
```

in the for header.

Comment: Well, you were right. Feeling kinda embarassed now :D